# setting a new position after changing attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

after changing the image attribute I wanna moving it ahead but seems like it's not changing even after using the .css method : this is my JS code

```
<script>
window.setTimeout(function(){
$( '#m').append( "<div id='CDT492'  class='plane' style='left: 199px; top:110px;'><div class='dot'><img id='trans'class='plimg' src='{% static 'img/plane3.png' %}'></div><div class='info_wrapper noalert'><div class='callsign'>CDT492 B735</div><div class='info'></div></div></div>" );
$('#arrival_sortable').append("<li class='ui-state-default' id='psFFT972' flightid='FFT972'><div style='padding:5px;'><div class='left callSign'>CDT492</div><div class='left' style='padding-left:10px;'>B735</div><div class='clearfix'></div><div class='left currTaxiway'>D</div><div class='left flightStatus' style='padding-left:10px;'>Landing</div><div class='left gate' style='padding-left:10px;'>B3</div><div class='clearfix'></div></div></li>");
$( "#CDT492" ).animate({ "left": "+=274px" ,"top":"+=170px"},{duration:15000,queue: false,
step: function(now) {
                if (now >= 467) {
                    $('#trans').attr("src","{% static 'img/rot.png' %}");
                    $('#CDT492').animate('top','+=5px');
                }
            } }
        );
    }, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Why do you use `window.setTimeout`?
   Do you know about `$(document).ready` event (there is a short form of this: `$(function() { ... });`)?
2. May be your code is not working because DOM is not ready yet and code could not find `#m` or `#arrival_sortable` element.
3. If your `#CDT492` element does not have position style you need to set it: `style='position: relative;`.
4. What do you want to do there: `if (now >= 467)`?
   I think, you need to check the value of the second handler parameter too (`tween` in JQuery documentation: `step: function(now, tween) { ... }`)
5. There is no any `css()` methods in your code.
6. Check whether you have no elements with the same `id` on the page.

So, that code works for me somehow.

```js
$(function() {
$( '#m').append( "<div id='CDT492'  class='plane' style='position: relative; left: 199px; top:110px;'><div class='dot'><img id='trans'class='plimg' src='{% static 'img/plane3.png' %}'></div><div class='info_wrapper noalert'><div class='callsign'>CDT492 B735</div><div class='info'></div></div></div>" );
$( "#CDT492" ).animate({ "left": "+=274px" ,"top":"+=170px"},{duration:15000,queue: false,
step: function(now, tween) {
                if (now >= 467) {
                    $('#trans').attr("src","{% static 'img/rot.png' %}");
                    $('#CDT492').animate('top','+=5px');
                }
            }}
        );
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="m"></div>
```

Comment: Im using set time out because each time I show a new icon ( working on airplane ground simulation)